# Run python script from Flask server

Tags: python, html, flask

I need to be able to run a Python script from my HTML file on my Flask server. On my HTML page, there is 3 input boxes, and an `ok` button. When the `ok` button is pressed, it should pass the number in the input boxes into a command to run a python script. An example of the command that would need to be run is `python magicHome-rgb.py <inputBox1> <inputBox2> <inputBox3>`, but replacing the `<inputBox[no]>` with the input from the input box.

If this doesn't make sense, feel free to ask more...

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and even if you could, don't. Instead, if you are using forms to gather your data, send that data to your Flask server with a POST request and have a function handle it. Don't use a separate script.

Example python function:

```
@app.route('/your-url', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def get_input():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            box1 = request.form['inputbox1']
            box2 = request.form['inputbox2']
            box3 = request.form['inputbox3']

            # -- do stuff --

        return render_template('your_template.html')
```

HTML example of a form that might be used:

```html
  <form method="post">
    <input type=number name="inputbox1" id="inputbox1" required/>
    <input type=number name="inputbox2" id="inputbox2" required/>
    <input type=number name="inputbox3" id="inputbox3" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
  </form>
```

In the above case, `box1`, `box2`, and `box3` store the outputs of the 3 input boxes that you might need.

Alternatively, to run code from the HTML file, you could also process the input with javascript embedded in the HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have tried your code, and I get the following errors: https://i.imgur.com/GOpfr1o.png

Comment: You will have to import request from Flask for the code to work. Eg: from flask import request. My bad.